# error: type mismatch in Spark JDBC read when passing values using a variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to fetch data from a table using spark jdbc read.

```
var df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("sep", ",").load("abfss://test@a.dfs.core.windows.net/data/raw")

import org.apache.spark.sql
df = df.withColumn("CustomerID", $"CustomerID".cast(sql.types.IntegerType)).withColumn("LAST_UPDATED", $"LAST_UPDATED".cast(sql.types.DateType))
val customerIds = df.select("CustomerID").collect()
val inCondition = "('" + customerIds.mkString("','") + "')"
val jdbcData = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> jdbcUrl, "dbtable" -> "(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SinkCustomers] WHERE CustomerID IN ("+ inCondition +")) AS C")).load()
```

But the output is,

```
 found   : String
 required: (?, ?)
 .options(Map("url" -> jdbcUrl, "dbtable" -> "(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SinkCustomers] WHERE CustomerID IN ("+ inCondition +")) AS C"))
```

Gives this error and I tried to put a hard coded int value as well. But still fails. But If I run `(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SinkCustomers] WHERE CustomerID IN (12323)) AS C")` this works well. Is it incorrect the way that I do the string concatenation or is it a customerIds issue? What I can do to solve this?

Comment: First output the ```dbtable``` variable to view its value.

Answer (score 0):

Use string interpolation `s".."` to properly build your query.

```scala
   spark
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .options(Map("url" -> jdbcUrl, "dbtable" -> s"(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SinkCustomers] WHERE CustomerID IN ($inCondition)) AS C"))
      .load()
```

Off-topic: I would avoid `var df` and go for multiple `val`variables